# How can I disable replay events in Sentry?

Tags: javascript, sentry

We dont use the replay feature of Sentry

And it's sending a massive number of events :

```
{"type":"replay_event"}
```

There seem to be no way to deactivate it in the admin settings.

Any idea on how to deactivate it through Sentry.init({}) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replay will only be enabled if you explicitly opt in. Could you share your init block? It will contain:

At least one of the two with non 0 values:

`replaysSessionSampleRate`
`replaysOnErrorSampleRate`

If you remove them. No replay will be sent.

In case you're using the sentry Loader instead. Where you just add the script tag yo your site. You can turn off sentry replay without redeploying your app.

In the project setting you go to Client Keys (DSN), click on Configure and the options for controlling performance monitoring and replay will be there.

Docs at https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/session-replay/

Comment: Thanks a lot. We're using Sentry for Browser Javascript. I didn't see that further in the installation doc, there are alternative script tag to process only errors and/or performance and/or replays : https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/install/loader/